# MongoDB: Finding to words, then counting the coincidences

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a database of books that looks like this:

```
{"_id": ObjectID("1"), "title": "Harry Potter", "year": NumberInt(2000), "author": "JK. Rowling", "genres" : [fantasy, drama]}, 
{"_id": ObjectID("2"), "title": "Harry Potter 99", "year": NumberInt(2020), "author": "JK. Rowling", "genres" : [fantasy, drama]}, 
{"_id": ObjectID("3"), "title": "Book", "year": NumberInt(2020), "author": "Mr. Author", "genres" : [war, romance]}, 
{...}
```

I would like to get the books that have the combination of the genres "fantasy" and "drama", converting their titles to capital letter, counting them, and finally getting an average of their year of publishment. Something like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ["HARRY POTTER", "HARRY POTTER 99],
  "yearavg" : "2010",
  "count" : "2"
}
```

I can't get through the grouping, so I've wrote this so far, it is not working though:

```
query1 = {"genres" : "Fantasy"}
query2 = {"genres" : "Drama"}
logic = {$and : [query1, query2]}
phase1 = {$match : logic}
phase2 = {$group : {"_id" : "$title", "year" : "$year"}}
phase3 = {$project : {"total" : {"$size" : "$genres"}, "genres" : 1}} 

steps = [phase1, phase2, phase3]
db.genres.aggregate(steps)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$match` genres are in all `["fantasy", "drama"]` array
- `$group` by null and make titles array after converting to upper case using `$toUpper`, get average year using `$avg`, get count using `$sum`

```
db.genres.aggregate([
  { $match: { genres: { $all: ["fantasy", "drama"] } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      titles: { $push: { $toUpper: "$title" } },
      yearavg: { $avg: "$year" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aZj8KhB-FDf)

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect. There is any way that I can make the average year an integer?

Comment: i can see it in integer right if i am not wrong?, for type conversion you can use `$toInt` operator.